# Jquery Resize Resolution Vice Versa

Tags: jquery

When you run this code (see link) and the WIDTH is larger than 600px, the links will turn GREEN and are clickable. If you REDUCE the resolution using the MIDDLE bar to be smaller than 600px, the links will turn RED and the links will be disabled. This is good!

The issue is if you RUN the code initially when the screen is SMALLER than 600px, the code will turn RED, yes, but if you INCREASE the resolution using the MIDDLE bar, the links will **not** turn back to GREEN. I'm trying to get the jquery to run in either resolution appropriately.

*(I'm looking for a simple plug-in like this without needing a larger library)*

DEMO: **http://jsfiddle.net/Fe4vG/3/**

**What am I doing wrong with this so I can get the jquery to run in either resolution appropriately?**

```
var eventFired = 0;

if ($(window).width() > 600) {
    $('a').css( "color", "green" );
}
else {
    $('a').click(false);
    $('a').css( "color", "red" );
    eventFired = 1;
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (!eventFired) {
        if ($(window).width() > 600) { //larger than 600 res
            $('a').unbind('click'); //enable click
            $('a').css( "color", "green" ); //change to green
        } else { //smaller than 600 res
            $('a').click(function () {return false;});//disable click
            $('a').css( "color", "red" ); //change to red
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove anything referencing `eventFired`. You don't really need this.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqZJ4/)

```
//var eventFired = 0;

if ($(window).width() > 600) {
    $('a').css( "color", "green" );
}
else {
    $('a').click(false);
    $('a').css( "color", "red" );
    //eventFired = 1;
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    //if (!eventFired) {
        if ($(window).width() > 600) { //larger than 600 res
            $('a').unbind('click'); //enable click
            $('a').css( "color", "green" ); //change to red
        } else { //smaller than 600 res
            $('a').click(function () {return false;});//disable click
            $('a').css( "color", "red" ); //change to green
        }
    //}
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your observation. thanks! hopefully this will help someone else, too.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the code initially, `eventFired` is set to `1`. The condition inside the event handler (`!eventFired`) is never true, so no action ever takes place.